# In Go code, how can I read the content appended to a bin file

Tags: go

I build Go code to binary file (bin/app),  then append a string to the binary file by using below command:

```
echo -n -e \\x66\\x6f\\x6f  >> bin/app
```

If you open the binary file with a txt editor, you will find the added content `666f 6f` after `0000`, which is right:

```
7465 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
666f 6f
```

The question is how can I read the content `666f 6f` appendeded to the binary in Go code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider using the [embed package](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) to embed data in the executable.

Comment: The embed package is certainly preferable for what you're trying to do, and you should definitely use it if the data is available at compile time. If it isn't, then there's nothing special about your binary. It's a file like every other and can be read with the facilities provided in the os and io packages.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally there have been third party packages (e.g. `go-bindata`) available to append data to Go binaries, but as of Go 1.16, there is the even more convenient built-in `embed` package to do that.

All you have to do to accomplish what you asked is to "anonymously" import `embed` and then use the `go:embed` directive to make the content of the file `text.txt` available as the variable `txt`:

```
package main

import _ "embed"
import "fmt"

//go:embed text.txt
var txt string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(txt);
}
```

For binary data as in your example, it's more convenient to use a slice of bytes:

```
//go:embed data.bin
var b []byte
```

For more details, see [this blog post](https://threkk.medium.com/embedding-files-natively-in-go-1-16-2a2f2070617d) and [the official docs](https://pkg.go.dev/embed@master).

Comment: Thank you for your qUick feedback! Does it mean that I need to rebuild the bin for each config file if using embed? Not just exec echo command.

Comment: @aaronchen2k: yes, if the embedded files change, the binary has to be rebuilt.

Comment: I'd like to echo config to bin file, without rebuild.